# What does the :1 at the end of css mean or stand for?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple update to a css file which, when viewed in Chrome Developer Tools, looks like this colorbox5.min.css:1   (understand that this is the minified version)

Another file at this location called colorbox.css:1

The update I'm trying to make is from:

```
#colorbox {outline: 0;}
```

to this:

```
#colorbox {outline: 0; color:#333;}
```

Editing either of these files has no effect, yet if I edit these live in Developer Tools it shows the desired effect?

Two questions then, which version is used - the minified version or the full? How do I get my update to show?

Comment: Number after the `:` tells you at which line of the filename is the rule used. When you have minified CSS file, everything is on line 1, it means in `file.css:1`.

Comment: Which build process are you using?

Comment: `#colorbox {outline: 0; color: #333 !important; )` do that in whichever/both css files and see if that does anything. If not, then it might be your cache.

Answer (score 3):

:1 is the line number in the css file. Because you have a minified version of your css file, its line 1.

When you edit something in the dev tools, it will not save your file on the filesystem, unless you use a plugin that can handle it for you.

Maybe your css file is cached, so try to clear your cache and reload again. In dev tools, you can specify not to cache css/scripts file while its open.